# Joining two indirectly related tables without including columns from tables in between

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select

Based on the following ERD, I'm trying to write a query that displays reservations made directly by customers and include reservation id, reservation date, customer id, customer first name, tour trip id, tour category name, tour trip date

[image]

I've been able to include everything in my query except for the tour category name because the TOUR_SITES table is in the way. Is there a way I can join the category name from the TOUR_PACKAGE table without adding any extra columns?

```
  SELECT  r.RESERVATION_ID, r.RESERVATION_DATE, 
c.CUSTOMER_ID, c.FIRST_NAME,t.TRIP_ID, o.TRIP_DATE/*, P.CATEGORY_NAME*/

FROM CUSTOMER c 
INNER JOIN RESERVATION r
ON
r.CUSTOMER_ID=c.CUSTOMER_ID

INNER JOIN TOURTRIP_RESERVATION t
ON
r.RESERVATION_ID=t.RESERVATION_ID

INNER JOIN TOUR_TRIP O
ON
t.TRIP_ID=o.TRIP_ID


WHERE AGENT_ID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can join the category name from the TOUR_PACKAGE table without adding any extra columns?

Sure; just join all tables you need. You don't have to add additional columns (the ones you don't need) into the `select` column list, but you do have to use the `tour_sites` table anyway.

Something like this:

```
select  r.reservation_id, r.reservation_date, 
  c.customer_id, c.first_name,t.trip_id, o.trip_date,
  p.category_name
from customer c inner join reservation r on r.customer_id=c.customer_id
inner join tourtrip_reservation t on r.reservation_id=t.reservation_id
inner join tour_trip o on t.trip_id=o.trip_id
--
join tour_sites s on s.tour_siteid = o.tour_siteid       --> add 
join tour_package p on p.category_id = s.category_id     --> this
where agent_id is null;
```

Comment: Perfect. thank you so much for the prompt solution!

Answer (score 1):

You need to first join tour_sites with tour_trip on TOUR_SITEID and then join tour_package with tour_sites on category_id to get the tour category_name. You can join left join on tour_sites in case there are no tour sites assigned for a tour trip like a newly added tour_trip.

```
SELECT  r.RESERVATION_ID, r.RESERVATION_DATE, c.CUSTOMER_ID, c.FIRST_NAME,t.TRIP_ID, o.TRIP_DATE,TP.CATEGORY_NAME
FROM CUSTOMER c 
INNER JOIN RESERVATION r ON r.CUSTOMER_ID=c.CUSTOMER_ID
INNER JOIN TOURTRIP_RESERVATION t ON r.RESERVATION_ID=t.RESERVATION_ID
INNER JOIN TOUR_TRIP O ON t.TRIP_ID=o.TRIP_ID
LEFT JOIN TOUR_SITES TS ON TS.TOUR_SITEID =  O.TOUR_SITEID
INNER JOIN TOUR_PACKAGE TP ON TP.CATEGORY_ID = TS.CATEGORY_ID 
WHERE AGENT_ID IS NULL;
```